# Xcode: can't see compile errors in my static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.seriousmonster.com/mixing-arc-and-non-arc-code-with-static-libraries/) to create a static library.

I have:

- Created the new target in my project (static library)
- Set its use ARC flag to no
- Linking to it from my App
- Adding it as a dependency
- Create a very simple function in the generated class (of the static library) that returns the string "hello World"
- From my apps delegate , I am logging the string returned that static library

Everything works fine !

So, whats the problem? I was a bit curious so I added a dummy line that causes compilation error to the function that returns the "Hello world" string.

The project's shows build fail whenever I rebuild it but it doesn't show the compilation error details (i.e. error description , file , line etc...) the errors tab is empty !

I hope you can help me with this, I am using Xcode 4.2.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just restarted xCOde and it works !